# Black Screen with nothing but a static word "GRUB" while attempting to install Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I have an HP Pavillion DV6 laptop that came with Windows 7 pre-installed. The laptop has an intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M processor with 2.3 GHz speed, and an Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 graphics card. The harddrive is 1TB and RAM 8GB.

Now I want to install Ubuntu 22.04 and delete the Windows.

I downloaded an Ubuntu Desktop ISO on my MAC and created a bootable PenDrive on my MAC with balanaEtcher.

Now when I try using this Pendrive to install Ubuntu on my HP laptop, all I see is a black static terminal-like screen with the word "GRUB" right where the prompt should have been if it were a terminal window. Everything just stays like that, static. I am new to Ubuntu and the command line.

I am wondering what the problem is. I have searched the site and found no solution. Is my HP laptop too old for Ubuntu 22.04, or should I have made the bootable pendrive on my HP laptop instead of making it on my MAC?

Any advice that can help is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You weren't specific as to which Ubuntu 22.04 you're talking about, ie. 22.04 Server? 22.04 Desktop? or 22.04 *flavor*?  which 22.04 ISO, ie. 22.04? 22.04.1? 22.04.2? as this can make a difference (esp. with regards kernel stack & what's included).  Did you verify the ISO prior to write?  I'd verify the write of ISO to media on another device (*do you have another handy?*) as your details don't rule out issues with the steps you performed.. Did you try *safe graphics* mode?

Comment: Your ISO file was probably damaged during the BalanaEtcher phase. You can verify the ISO against the fingerprint on the website, as @guiverc mentioned, or try again (with another stick, if you have one).

Comment: @guiverc I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop. I verified the ISO using `echo "b98dac940a82b110e6265ca78d1320f1f7103861e922aa1a54e4202686e9bbd3 *ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check`

Comment: @Jos Verifying the ISO prior to flashing returns an OK (ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso: OK). I have also tried flashing the Pendrive again and it yielded the same outcome. What I haven't been able to do is very the ISO against the fingerprint on the Ubuntu site because I am stuck at fetching the keys from the key server. I keep getting this response; (gpg: keyserver receive failed: Network is unreachable).

Comment: I tried holding the SHIFT key while the PC was booting up and got a slightly different result. Instead of just a static blank black screen with the word GRUB, I got a static blank black screen with the word GRUB, followed by the word "loading." And then it just stayed there, has been like that ever since.

Comment: I have just tried using the Pendrive to install Ubuntu on another PC, a DELL Inspiron, and it worked just fine. So, I am guessing the issue must be from my laptop.

Comment: I agree that it is probably an issue with your laptop. If the Windows system still works, you may try to find out whether there is a BIOS update available.

Comment: @Jos It appears I have the latest BIOS version for the system installed.

Comment: If you have a BIOS you want to make/burn the USB stick in that 'format'. If you have an UEFI, make the device in GPT format.

Comment: @HomerSimpson How do I burn the USB stick in BIOS format? There is no option in Etcher for that. And I have tested the USB stick on another machine with a BIOS and it works just fine.

Comment: Do you have 'Fast Boot' in Windows disabled?

Comment: @HomerSimpson I am not sure. I'll have to double-check that. However, I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday and it works just fine. So I am thinking it has to do with some incompatibility issue between Ubuntu 22.04.2 and something in my machine.

Comment: You could opt for installing 20.04 and upgrade to 22.04. It is more work but it could work.